# Drag and drop use JavaScript in Selenium Java but fail to run

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DemoJavascriptDragAnDrop {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to("https://demoqa.com/droppable");
        // Find the source and target elements
        WebElement sourceElement = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
        WebElement targetElement = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));

        // Scroll both source and target elements into view
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", sourceElement);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", targetElement);
        Thread.sleep(300);

        // Perform drag-and-drop using JavaScriptExecutor
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].simulateDragDrop(arguments[1])", sourceElement, targetElement);

    // Close the browser
    //driver.quit();
}

}
```

I encounter a error in log as below

> Command: [155a02d202cd9364a0fb97a1d3bc31f5, executeScript {script=arguments[0].simulateDragDrop(arguments[1]), args=[{element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=6D600EA7D2AA88FE68FF6844DE8C378E_element_18}, {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=6D600EA7D2AA88FE68FF6844DE8C378E_element_27}]}]

I can run with Actions. However I want to try with JavaExecutor.